# How to access the updated datasource from the UICollectionView.CellRegistration

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, datasource, uicollectionviewcell

I was wondering why the data source's value is updated, but when I access a single value from cell registration the value is not changed.
The code below is what I mean.

I have a struct called Event, which takes three values, id, name, and streamState

```
struct Event: Codable, Hashable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let streamState: String
}

struct Events: Codable {
    let streams: [Event]
}
```

In my EventDataSource class, I have an array of Events and the fetchEvent function for getting the event data from the backend, and to make this simple, I only add 1 data (1 event), so I know events array has only one data now.

```
class EventDataSource {
    var events = [Event]()

    func fetchEvents(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
            AF.request(myEndpoint)
            .validate()
                .responseJSON { response in
                    
                    guard let data = response.data else { return }
                    let decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                    var result: Events?
                    
                    do {
                        result = try decoder.decode(Events.self, from: data)
                    } catch {
                        print("error with fetch events: \(error)")
                    }
                    
                    guard let final = result else { return }      
                    self.events = final.streams

                    if events.count > 0 {
                        print("fetched first item: \(self.events[0].streamState), \(events[0].name)") // -> get the updated streamState with correct name
                    }
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion()
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

In the code above, I added the if statement (`events.count > 0`) to make sure the event's streamState is updated. (more specifically, the event's streamState is start from `init`, but after a couple of seconds later, it becomes `ready`, and I get `ready` is printed, so I think I can say the streamState is successfully changed on the backend.)

I display the event data using CollectionViewListCell, and whenever I update the Event data using the fetchEvents function in the EventDataSource, I call the displayEvents function to update the collectionViewListCell. Then since the cell is recreated, the cellRegistration part is also called. I printed what's in the `event.streamState`, but it gives me the original value (`init`), even though the fetched data in the `fetchEvents` function clearly give me the updated value (`ready`).

```
class ListViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    private var collectionViewDataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Event>?
    private var snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Event>!
    private var eventDataSource = EventDataSource()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        displayEvents()
        configureDataSource()

    }

    func displayEvents() {
        snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Event>()
        snapshot.appendSections([.list])
        snapshot.appendItems(eventDataSource.Events)
        collectionViewDataSource?.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func configureDataSource() {
        let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<CustomListCell, Event> { cell, indexPath, event in
        print(event.streamState) // -> this value is not changed, only gives me the original value
        cell.event = event
    }

    collectionViewDataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Event (collectionView: collectionView) { (collectionView, indexPath, event) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: event)
        return cell
    }
}
```

I looked up some other articles and googled, but I still have no idea why the updated value is printed. I feel stuck now and that's why I posted this question. If anyone can point me out to the right direction, please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

Invert the order of calls to `configureDataSource()` and `displayEvents()` in your `viewDidLoad()` implementation, otherwise you're applying a snapshot to a `nil` data source.
Plus you're setting the `collectionViewDataSource` out of the scope of `configureDataSource()`